# Swift Changing background colour of UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, background-color

I'm new to Swift. I looked everywhere in the storyboard but somehow can't change the background color of my tableview. Isn't there a way to change the background color from the storyboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift - How to change background color of Table View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679701/ios-swift-how-to-change-background-color-of-table-view)

Comment: click on the cell and change its background color to clear color. that will show the table's background color

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard set the background to clear color

[image]

and in your

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

set the color of the cell with

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```